# about android , webview Override shouldInterceptRequest method，but it make js code Failure

Tags: javascript, android, webview

thank you:

webview load a url(www.simple.com/step1.html),the response conntent

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        location.href = "/step2.html"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the js code do not work.Under normal circumstances, the final page will be step2. but is still in step1
when i Override shouldInterceptRequest  like :

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
             try {
                URL oUrl = new URL(request.getUrl().toString());

                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)oUrl.openConnection();
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(oUrl.getHost());
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(cookie))
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().toString()+";q=0.8");
                conn.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                conn.connect();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()){
                    @Override
                    public void close() throws IOException {
                        super.close();
                        if (conn != null) {
                            conn.disconnect();
                        }
                    }

                };

                return new WebResourceResponse(conn.getContentType(), conn.getContentEncoding(), bis);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you enable JavaScript in the WebView? The code is like this:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```